# System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied (UWP C#)

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, imgur, access-rights

I'm developing a uwp platform that permit to upload image to imgur with the imgur api.
I'm doing this :

```
var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
        picker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        picker.SuggestedStartLocation =
            Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
        String path;

        Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (file != null)
        {
            path = file.Path;
        }
        else
        {
            path = "Operation cancelled.";
        }
try
            {
                var client = new ImgurClient("id", "secret");
                var endpoint = new ImageEndpoint(client);
                IImage img;
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Yield();
                Debug.Write("crash at FileStream\n");
                using (var fs = new FileStream(@path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
                {
                    Debug.Write("crash at Upload\n");
                    img = await endpoint.UploadImageStreamAsync(fs);
                    Debug.Write("Image uploaded. Image Url: " + img.Link);
                    Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image image = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image();
                    image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(img.Link));
                    image.Width = img.Width;
                    image.Height = img.Height;
                    imgList.Clear();
                    imgList.Add(image);
                    await LoadGalery();
                    index = 0;
                }
            });
            }
            catch (ImgurException imgurEx)
            {
                Debug.Write("An error occurred uploading an image to Imgur.");
                Debug.Write(imgurEx.Message);
            }
```

I have this error :

> - $exception  {System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Nouveau dossier\mmmh.PNG' is denied.    at
>     System.IO.WinRTIOExtensions.d__2`1.MoveNext()
>     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>     task)    at
>     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>     task)    at System.IO.WinRTFileSystem.d__41.MoveNext()
>     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>     task)    at
>     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>     task)    at System.IO.WinRTFileSystem.Open(String fullPath, FileMode
>     mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize,
>     FileOptions options, FileStream parent)    at
>     System.IO.MultiplexingWin32WinRTFileSystem.Open(String fullPath,
>     FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize,
>     FileOptions options, FileStream parent)    at
>     System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>     access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)    at
>     System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>     access, FileShare share)    at
>     App1.MainPage.<>c__DisplayClass7_1.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
>     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>     task)    at
>     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>     task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>     at App1.MainPage.d__7.MoveNext()
>     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>     task)    at
>     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>     task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>     at
>     App1.MainPage.d__9.MoveNext()}    System.UnauthorizedAccessException

I tried to create a new directory in C:/ folder with my picture, change security rights, execute Visual studio as administrator but nothing changed...

The error happens on
var fs = new FileStream(@path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read

I've seen many topics about this all the day i've tried everything but nothing change if someone have any idea !

Comment: can you recreate writing to directory in %appdata%

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When user selects an arbitrary file using `FileOpenPicker`, you get a `StorageFile` instance. This is the only way you can access the file, you cannot use the `Path` directly, as that API is not under the WinRT sandbox. You can access only files in your app's `AppData` directory directly with `Path`.

You can however get a stream from the retrieved `StorageFile` bu calling the appropriate extension method:

```
var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
```

### Update

Information in this post is now outdated. Since April 2018 update of Windows 10 you can declare a Broad Filesystem access capability that will allow your app to access any path in the filesystem even with the `System.IO` APIs. This capability is however checked during certification so you have to make sure the app has a good reason to have access to all of the user's filesystem, because your app will be rejected otherwise, to prevent malicious misuse.

Answer (score 4):

> Since April 2018 update of Windows 10 you can declare a >Broad Filesystem access capability that will allow your app >to access any path in the filesystem even with the >System.IO APIs.

NO It does not

```
StorageFile file = await 
StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync("c:\\1\\1.txt");

//string s = File.ReadAllText("C:\\1\\1.txt");
//string s = await 
File.ReadAllTextAsync("C:\\1\\1.txt");

string text = await 
Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);

var dialog = new MessageDialog("done");
await dialog.ShowAsync();
```

StorageFile works OK, but System.IO have a System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'C:\1\1.txt' is denied.'

Comment: I just found that out as well. Did you find a way to fix that problem? (other than using the StorageFile API)

Answer (score 1):

According to the Microsoft Docs, UWP apps are sandboxed, meaning (unlike a console app) they have limited access to the computer's resources.  It is possible to grant additional capabilities to a UWP app by modifying the `Package.appxmanifest`.

These links have the full story:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#custom-capabilities
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions